# What web server / plat form should I use? (Cloud / virtual / dedicated / shared)

Tags: linux, cloud, virtualization, share

Hi I am an experienced website developer but have not had much experiences of hardware server con fig.

I am starting a new job and need to sort out the companies website requirements.

They need php mysql format so a linux route.

Also they currently have 5 cms based sites that will have probably no more than 1000 visits a day max for the foreseeable future.  But the number of sites and visits will hopefully grow in the future.  There is currently no heavy media etc on the sites so I dont think they need anything super heavy.

I am unsure which route to follow:

- Dedicated - sounds expensive
- Virtual  / cloud - sounds like the best fit (Rackspace cloud / Amazon web
  services)
- Shared server / hosting - not so keen on due to lack of flexibility.

Obviously price is a consideration but there is money there to spend.

Anyone have any recommendations or more pros / cons per platform???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing is you have a lot of options when you start out with a low traffic website. I wouldn't go with something dedicated with such low traffic. Shared servers are a dieing bunch with the cost not much better than virtual. Virtual should treat you good, I would head that way.

Each virtual provider has their own pros/cons that you can find a lot of punditry on. The best thing to do is test and that is pretty easy to do these days. AWS is going to have the least friction to get started but Rackspace isn't too bad. I have used [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) for 8 years and they are great too, I haven't had to use their support but I hear it is the best.

Another tip to think about is AWS has their RDS database service that can be pretty nice if you just want to spin up a MySQL instance without having to think about it. The downside is that it is a little expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I think your headed in the right direction looking at the cloud.  Some other reasons this make sense are.

- no need to pay a dedicated sys-admin (This is great for getting off the ground and minimizing costs)
- Scalability (Just make sure you program for it)
- Minimize infrastructure costs (No need to purchase switches routers UPS units etc etc)